# if i use a more general selector, how do I grab it so I can call .parent() on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm new to js and coffee, and having trouble with the following code. with the `this.parent()` I am trying to find the parent of the particular instance of the element which has been click.

```
$('#attachment-container').on 'click', '.attachment-success .remove-attachment', ->
  id = this.parent().data('attachment-id')
  $('#attachment-container [data-attachment-id=id]').remove()
```

running `console.log(this.parent())`, i get error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'parent'`

`console.log(this)` returns:

```
 <button class="close remove-attachment">×</button>
```

i think there's a problem, because to call .parent, i'm expecting the result to be:

```
[<button class="close remove-attachment">×</button>]
```

(I lack language required to describe the difference sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not a jQuery object, so it doesn't have the jQuery method `parent`. Wrap it: `$(this)`. `$(this).parent()` should work.